# Photon Unity Networking Unwanted Cross-scene Instantiation

Tags: unity-game-engine, network-programming, multiplayer, photon

I have one big problem with PUN, and that is that PhotonNetwork.Instantiate instantiates objects on a per-room basis, not a per-scene basis. The setup I have right now is one "server", the master client, and then everyone else joins the same room. This is because I need to be able to send RPC calls to the server before gameplay, for login and character creation purposes.

The problem with this is that players already in the world will show up in the login and character creation scene of any new player's client, and will disappear when the player changes scenes. Ideally, I would like to only instantiate the players that are in the same scene as the client, but I have no idea how to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Having one room per scene is convenient way of handling scenes with PUN.
Why can't you disconnect "lobby" room and connect "game" one when scenes change?

Answer (score 0):

Call PhotonNetwork.Instantiate when all the users are present in the game scene.

Before starting game check if all the players have successfully loaded the game scene. If acknowledgment is received from every player than call PhotonNetwork.Instantiate and start the game.

Comment: The only problem with this is that the game scene needs to have a dynamic amount of players. I can't wait for everyone to join before calling PhotonNetwork.Instantiate because I want people to be able to join at any time during the game.

Comment: If thats the case then just simply preserve the object when any scene is loaded and dont let it destroy on load. Use DontDestroyOnLoad for Gameobject

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html